# Angujar2, how can read component in string?

Tags: angular

Angujar2, how can read component in string?

test component(director)

section : app-test

---

main component
html :

```
<app-test>text</app-test>
```

i want getter  inner text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<ng-content></ng-content>`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
})
```

To get the content in a variable

```
export class AppTestComponent {

   content;

   constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {

   }

   ngOnInit() {
      this.content = this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHtml;
   }
}
```